# FCM Device Group iOS app badge update causes empty push on android

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Goal;** Update iOS app badge counter with silent push through FCM device group containing both Android and iOS devices.

**Problem;** All Android devices in the device group receives user-visible push with no content.

I have tried a lot of different approaches to this, but I am struggling to find a solution.

With the legacy http-api with body `{"to":"someToken", "notification":{"badge": "23"}}` I am successfully silently updating the iOS app badge, but any registered android device on the same device group also receives a push message with nothing in it, which is visible for the user.

The V1 API where you can set `apns` directly does not appear support device groups. when I set the device group token in the `token` field, the api returns 200, but nothing happens. However, I am able to send messages from the Firebase notification console when setting the "Single device" to a device group token, which makes me believe this should be possible, but I am somehow doing it wrong.

According to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group), you should be able to use the [Message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) data structure with the legacy api, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Below are a few of my tested approaches.

---

HTTP v1 API code for sending request;

```
import * as rp from 'request-promise'
var options: any = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' + FCMProjectName + '/messages:send',
        headers: headers, // Header gotten by means described here; https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server
        json: true,
        body: experimentalBody
    };
rp(options)
.then(function(result){
    console.log("result", result)
})
```

The legacy code is essentially very similar, but different URI and different headers.

I have tried several `experimentalBody`. I can't even get the trivial case to work with device groups;

```
experimentalBody = {
    message: {
        token: "validDeviceGroupToken",
        notification: {
            "title":"Check out this sale!",
            "body":"All items half off through Friday"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried;

```
experimentalBody = {
    token: "validDeviceGroupToken",
    notification: {
        title:"Check out this sale!",
        body:"All items half off through Friday"
    }
}
```

No more luck when setting priority;

```
experimentalBody = {
    message: {
        token: "validDeviceGroupToken",
        notification: {
            title:"Test!",
            body:"This is a test"
        },
        apns: {
            headers: {
                "apns-priority": "10"
            }
        },
        android: {
            priority: "HIGH"
        }
    }
```

All of these return `success { name: 'projects/my-project/messages/' }`, but it appears as though it should have returned something like `success { name: 'projects/my-project/messages/SOMETHINGHERE' }`.

With the legacy api, the following code does work on iOS, but sends empty notification to android;

```
experimentalBody = {
    to: "validDeviceGroupToken",
    notification: {
        badge: 23
    }
}
```

I have also tried using the `message` object from V1 in the legacy code, but it does not appear to work. I get a response of `body: "to\n"`, which I suspect mean that I need "to" in the body, but I am not sure.

Comment: I have been in contact with Firebase. This is apparently a bug from their side. They have it in their bug-tracker, and will hopefully get to it soon.